# WinRT - frame navigation and AppBars

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

I'm trying to implement custom navigation system for WinRT (specifically - Windows Phone 8.1). Instead of usual page navigation, I want to create a HostPage, which will include a single Frame. I'll turn every page into a UserControl and navigation service will set HostPage's Frame to a cached instance of UserControl. I works just fine, but I have a problem with BottomAppBar. I can't figure out how to define CommandBar in UserControl and bind it to the HostPage. Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of UserControl, you should use Page like normal.

Comment: Look at https://github.com/faisalr/HamburgerBinding it passes the frame to the host constructor.

Comment: Thank you, but that's not what I'm looking for. I want one, persistent Page.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

Define its contents as a DataTemplate in the UserControl's resources (with a common key). Then in the HostPage you can get it from the UserControl.Resources[YourCommonKey], and set it as the CommandBar's contents.

Use this method to load the DataTemplate's contents: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.loadcontent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you, but sadly it doesn't work - AppBar is always empty.
AppBar is defined in HostPage like this:
`<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar x:Name="AppBar">
     </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>` . UserControl: http://pastebin.com/DHzv7Qus .

Do you have any idea how those definitions should look like?

Comment: Can you show me your code for adding the items from the userconotrol's resources to the appbar?

Comment: Interesting, I don't see any issues with it :( I'll have to look into this a bit more.

Comment: I'll appreciate it greatly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the xaml to create the Page.BottomAppBar. Use:

```
CommandBar bar = new CommandBar();
AppBarButton appBarButton = new AppBarButton();
BitmapIcon bi = new BitmapIcon();
bi.UriSource = item.Uri;
appBarButton.Icon = bi;
appBarButton.Label = item.Text;
appBarButton.Click += (sender, e) => item.Action();
yourPageRef.BottomAppBar = bar;
ApplicationBar.PrimaryCommands.Add(appBarButton);
```

Then you can keep references wherever you like. The idea is that there will only be one CommandBar and you can clear and add buttons depending on the UserControl.